# Is there any way to use domain name of old website with project on Google Cloud Compute Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a website on Compute Engine and it runs on `localhost:3000`. I have a domain name, I used on another website, hosted on **domain.by**. How can I use this domain name with my new website on GCP Compute Engine?

***Some edits:***

I have trouble accessing my website by external IP address. I allowed HTTP and HTTPS traffic in my instance settings.

Here are some screenshots ( I can translate from Russian if you need ):
[image]

[image]

**IP type:**
Static

**IP version:**
IPv4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a static IP address that should be associated with your Compute Engine as opposed to an ephemeral IP address.  You can do this is the GCP Cloud Console.  At this point, your compute engine will have a permanent IP address.   Now you can reach your web server by its IP address.  To associate a domain name with this IP address you would contact your DNS provider (or use their self-service admin console assuming it exists) to associate your DNS name with your IP address via a "DNS 'A' Record".  This maps your DNS name to your IP address.

Now DNS lookups should resolve.  Finally, you are likely going to have to define GCP VPC network firewall rules to allow incoming traffic (from the Internet) also known as Ingress to pass through.  Typically you setup a Web Server to listen on ports 80 (http) and 443 (https).  If you need to use https then you are likely going to have to obtain an SSL certificate but that is a very different story.

Comment: thanks! I've set a static IP, as you said, but when I type it in Chrome is says: check internet connection

Comment: Did you open the firewall allowing incoming traffic on port 80?  This is a commonly negelected step that would result in a symptom as you described.

Comment: I allowed HTTPS and HTTP traffic if you are talking about it.

Comment: Maybe update this question or post a new question about the issue.  I'd like to see the complete story to try and assist.  Specifically, I'd like to see the full text of the browser error message.

Comment: It's not en error, just simple message "this site can't be reached"

Comment: And in the browser you have specified what as the URL?

Comment: No, I didn't. Do I need to specify it in Google Cloud Console? And if yes, where this option is?

Comment: I will add some screenshots to my post with my settings.